# How to remove empty facet with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I am doing geom_point with ggplot using facet_grid, but i get facet empty and i do not know how to delete them or how to structure my data to not have empty facet ?

This is a example of my data :

```
data = data.frame(
  F1=c(0.69, 0.59, 0.6 , 0.52, 0.56, 0.58, 0.52, 0.53, 0.41, 0.57,
       0.54, 0.38, 0.48, 0.31, 0.35,
       0.43, 0.36, 0.38, 0.23, 0.48, 0.55, 0.48, 0.49, 0.46, 0.49,
       0.52, 0.48, 0.48, 0.35, 0.5 ,
       0.51, 0.58, 0.51, 0.59, 0.51, 0.57, 0.5 , 0.59, 0.47, 0.51,
       0.61, 0.58, 0.61, 0.59, 0.61, 0.67, 0.6 , 0.59, 0.47, 0.61,
       0.61, 0.52, 0.53, 0.60,0.62, 0.53, 0.62, 0.63, 0.24, 0.38),
  F2 = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01,
         0.42, 0.35, 0.43, 0.31, 0.34, 0.41, 0.34, 0.34, 0.42, 0.39, 0.44, 0.43,
         0.49, 0.43, 0.42, 0.53, 0.41, 0.42, 0.50, 0.40 ,
         0.53, 0.58, 0.57, 0.55, 0.51, 0.65, 0.51, 0.52, 0.62, 0.49,
         0.63, 0.68, 0.67, 0.66, 0.61, 0.66, 0.61, 0.62, 0.62, 0.49,
         0.84, 0.65, 0.69, 0.56, 0.72, 0.61, 0.73, 0.68, 0.72, 0.72),
  s1= c(rep(c("a"),10),
        rep(c("b"),10),
        rep(c("c"),10),
        rep(c("d"),10),
        rep(c("f"),10),
        rep(c("g"),10)),
  s2= c(rep(c("g1"),20),
        rep(c("g2"),40)),
  M=rep(c("M1",
          "M2",  
          "M3",    
          "M4",    
          "M5",   
          "M6",         
          "M7", 
          "M8",
          "M9",
          "M10"),6))
```

My code :

```
ggplot (data, aes (x = F1, y = F2, shape = M)) +
  facet_grid(s2 ~ s1) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(7,13,23,0,8,1,15,2,17,3,25))+
  geom_point ()
```

I get that :

[image]

Plot expected :
[image]

Comment: use `facet_wrap`

Comment: Of course I tried facet_wrap(s2 ~ s1) but it does not give me the result I want !

Comment: I tried your code but I do not get the  additional text on its right side . also I want to have only two facet on the same line and the extra text on the right

Comment: [This post](https://rpubs.com/m_dev/facet_wrap) on removing grobs may help you removing the empty panels, but you may want to move the remaining panels. Alternatively, you could use produce each individual plot with some subseting and the package [grid.extra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) to plot the resulting plots on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my question and I wanted to share it with you :

```
p <- qplot(data=data, x=F1, y=F2)+facet_wrap( ~ s1,ncol = 2)
z <- ggplotGrob(p)
gtable_show_layout(z)
z <- gtable_add_cols(z, unit(0.08, 'null'), 11)
gtable_show_layout(z)
z <- gtable_add_grob(z,
                     list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col=NA, fill = gray(0.85), size = 0.5,face="bold")),  
                          textGrob("g1", 
                                   rot = -90, gp = gpar(col = gray(0),fontsize=12,fontface = 'bold'))),
                     7, 12,9,12, name = paste(runif(2)))
gtable_show_layout(z)
z <- gtable_add_grob(z,
                     list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col=NA, fill = gray(0.85), size = 0.5,face="bold")),  
                          textGrob("g2", 
                                   rot = -90, gp = gpar(col = gray(0),fontsize=12,fontface = 'bold'))),
                     12, 12,18,12, name = paste(runif(2)))

z <- gtable_add_cols(z, unit(1/6, "line"),11)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(z)
```

[image: That's the graph I wanted to get]

I hope that my solution will be useful for other people !!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why facet_wrap wouldn't work

the code below produces what you want

```
p <- ggplot (data, aes (x = F1, y = F2, shape = M))
p <- p + geom_point () 
p <- p +  facet_wrap(s2 ~ s1,ncol=2) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(7,13,23,0,8,1,15,2,17,3,25))
p
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, your code adds the text g1 and g2 at the **top** , and I want the text g1 and g2 to be on the **right** as indicated in the photo in my poste !

Comment: @Axeman 's solution is probably better if you really want the display you showed. Otherwise the `labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line=FALSE)` argument to the facet_wrap call for saving space

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I'm still trying with the functions : **gtable_add_cols**, **gtable_add_grob** to get my plot

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* need to create that example output with strip labels on both sides, you'll need to create three plots, something like:

```
p3 <- ggplot(subset(data, s1 %in% c('f', 'g')), aes(F1, F2, shape = M)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(s2 ~ s1) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(7,13,23,0,8,1,15,2,17,3,25))
p1 <- p3 %+% subset(data, s1 %in% c('a', 'b')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), legend.position = 'none')
p2 <- p1 %+% subset(data, s1 %in% c('c', 'd'))

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, nrow = 3, align = 'v', axis = 'lr', rel_heights = c(1, 1, 1.2))
```

But I would generally go with the easier wrap solution by @Boidot.

Comment: I can't seem to attach an image, imgur appears to be having issues.

Comment: It's possible to have a one single title for the y-axis ?

Comment: I found a way to do the plot using the functions: gtable_add_cols, gtable_add_grob .. but I have a problem in the size of the added column [link]  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728292/how-to-add-column-with-gtable-add-cols)

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using the [`ggh4x`](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html) package with the `facet_manual` function to create a custom design layout based on your s1 and s2 columns like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

design = "
AB
CD
EF"

ggplot (data, aes (x = F1, y = F2, shape = M)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(7,13,23,0,8,1,15,2,17,3,25))+
  geom_point() +
  ggh4x::facet_manual(vars(s1,s2), design = design)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The ggh4x package makes this previously daunting task trivially simple.

Answer (score 0):

how about that approach?

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(F1, F2, shape = M, color = s2)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ s1) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(7,13,23,0,8,1,15,2,17,3,25))
```

plot is:

[image]

Comment: I found this Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 4, not 60 ! I'm trying to use qplot(data=data, x=F1, y=F2)+facet_wrap( ~ s1,ncol = 2) and add column with  gtable_add_cols ... but I have not succeeded yet !!! Thank you for helping me ... if you know how I can use these functions ....

Comment: sorry, i had the wrong dataset you have to replace `df` with `data`. I edited my answer. hope that helps.

Comment: sorry, @Axeman but thats basically wrong. I added the image in my answer. i recommend you to check the output first.

Comment: Your plot also doesn't need two `geom_point` layers. Just `ggplot(data, aes(F1, F2, shape = M, color = s2)) + geom_point() + ...` will do.